# Protractor tests fail, window too small

Tags: testing, protractor, automated-tests

I have the below bit of config set up for my Protractor tests. Even though I specify to set size of the window to 1600x1000px, it doesn't happen every time. Really often my tests fail because the window isn't resized and is really tiny. Some elements become unreachable because of this.

`browser.manage().window().setSize(1600, 1000);` should resize the window every time but sometimes ignores it? Is there a reason why it's happening?

```
exports.config = {
    onPrepare: function() {
        var location =(browser.params.logFileLocation==undefined?'':browser.params.logFileLocation);
        browser.manage().window().setSize(1600, 1000);
        jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(
            new Jasmine2HtmlReporter({
                savePath: './results'+ location,
                takeScreenshots: true,
                takeScreenshotsOnlyOnFailures: true,
                showPassed: false,
                fileName: 'test-results'
            })
        );
             .
             .
             .
     }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to set the screen size in your protractor.conf in capabilities. 
For Example:

```
capabilities: {
    browserName: 'chrome',
    chromeOptions: {
        args: ['--window-size=1600,1000']

        //or Fullscreen
        //args:["--start-maximized", "--start-fullscreen"],
    }
}
```

Comment: No difference. Still didn't resize the window. I think the problem is trying to resize window too quickly before it's even displayed.

Answer (score 0):

this will maximize your window

try this out

```
browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();
```